# Mailgun POST /messages API always throw 401 forbidden

Tags: android, mailgun

I am trying to send Mailgun POST /messages API request in Android using retrofit library.

Following is retrofit request:

HTTP POST https://api:key-xxx/v3/sandboxxxx/messages

Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 148

from=Excited+User+%3Cmailgun%40sandboxxxxmailgun.org%3E&to=vir.jain%40gmail.com&subject=Hello&text=Testing+awesomeness

Response:
HTTP 401 https://api:key-xxx/v3/sandboxxxx.mailgun.org/messages (1966ms)
Server: nginx/1.7.9
Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 10:00:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MG API"
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1434362440805
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1434362441086
Forbidden

When I try this same request on Postman, it works perfectly & email is sent properly. But when sending using retrofit library from Android fails with Forbidden.

My Retrofit API:
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/messages")
public void sendEmail(@Field("from") String from, @Field("to") String to, @Field("subject") String subject, @Field("text") String text, RestCallback objectRestCallback);

Base URL is: 
https://api:key-xxx/v3/sandboxxxsandboxxxx.mailgun.org

Everything is form URL encoded. But I'm really not sure what going wrong.
Can anyone please help me out whats wrong with above API?

Thank you,
Mahavir

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication ... *When I try this same request on Postman, it works perfectly* <= not possible(it is not the same) ... you need to pass some auth ...

Comment: Umm.. In Postman, I was sending auth params in URL itself "username:password@url" and it was working.. But same thing while calling in java using Retrofit library doesn't work.

Comment: Had the same issue trying to use Mailgun and Paw - accepted answer solved it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I added following authorization header with Base64 encoded string of API key to the request, it started working.

request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+getBase64String("api:key-xxxYOUR-API-KEY>"));

@Selvin: Thanks so much for sending wiki link :).

Comment: You will want to remove the apikey from this answer. You might have to contact Stackoverflow on how to remove the apikey from the history of the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify your mailgun region: `mg.SetAPIBase(mailgun.APIBaseEU)`

```
// Create an instance of the Mailgun Client
mg := mailgun.NewMailgun(yourDomain, privateAPIKey)
mg.SetAPIBase(mailgun.APIBaseEU)
```