# Getting 401 on post request to mailgun api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, mailgun, rest-client

Im trying to do a post request to send a email, this is my code:

```
 url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MYDOMAIN/messages"

    params = {
        :from => "Excited User <manuelbruno05@gmail.com>",
        :to => "bruno.brito.ln@gmail.com, YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
        :subject => "Hello",
        :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
    }

    headers = {
        :api => "MY-API-KEY"
    }

    RestClient.post url, params, headers
```

When i try to make a request, the response is 401 Unauthorized. Sending the request using *HttpRequester* works fine(response 200) so my guess is i'm setting headers wrong in Rails. My question: How can i fix this code?

Comment: Does MailGun require you to whitelist IPs or something to be able to send requests?  I'm assuming you're doing this call from your local machine which is where HTTPRequester worked as well? Are you sure the key is the same? I don't see why the call from Ruby would yield different results.

Comment: It doest not require ip whitelist, i'm doing from local where my HttpRequester is installed as well. Yes the key is the same i double checked.

Comment: I found this question that seems to be related to my problem, but i don't know to fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842841/mailgun-post-messages-api-always-throw-401-forbidden?rq=1

Comment: Ah well in my search I found a gem specific for Mailgun that should be way easier to use; https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby you instantiate a new class with the key and then use their methods to send/receive.

Comment: I'm going to try it

Comment: Does Mailgun actually accept an "Api" header? I thought they use HTTP basic authentication, so you should pass "api" as the user and your key as the password. https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication

Answer (score 3):

I got a 401 Forbidden because it was using the US server, while I was in the EU. I had to add a line to the `MailGun example Go` script

```
// Create an instance of the Mailgun Client 
mg:= mailgun.NewMailgun(yourDomain, privateAPIKey)

/// THIS is the line I had to add to get it to use the EU server.
mg.SetAPIBase(mailgun.APIBaseEU)
```

Comment: For me, using python, I had to replace the post url domain with `https://api.eu.mailgun.net` (note the .eu part)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the actual API key you obtained from the dashboard, and not the "key ID" that they emailed you. The two are not the same!

Answer (score -1):

I just experienced this, so I am dropping my solution here. You need to add 0.0.0.0/0 to IP whitelists on the Mailgun website. Right underneath the list of API keys.